# Minimize round-trips between client and database with oracle forms 10

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

our clients are working in particular conditions and their latency is high.

All our oracle forms 10 are calling a procedure that translates all the labels, etc that will be displayed in the form.  So for every label to translate, a call is made from the client to the database (the procedure translating the labels is a database package and the data is in a table).

We would like to reduce all these round trips and I was thinking that, if I can store locally (in a .jar?) the whole dictionary (around 1 meg when exported in text) I could  improve the performance.  Around 300 back&forth are actually done everytime we open a new form.

So my goal is to
- store locally some data
- be able locally (via an attached library?) to read the data

I am a bit lost.  How can I do it (st) and how can I access it?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: One solution might be to "bundle" the translations somehow on the database server, like maybe by:  a) providing a way that the application can issue a `SELECT` statement to the database to get all the translations at once, or, b) providing a new version of your database procedure that allows the application to pass a collection of the labels to be translated, and then returns a collection containing the results.

Comment: yeah that's the first thing I tried but I found that in many other places a call to the dictionnary is done.  If I can get the data locally instead of via the database I will have a solution that will reduce maybe 75% of the calls.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is make an attached library with a package with global constants for all your translations. Then you can call these, because this is a forms package and not a db package no calls are made.